# Google spreadsheet : different rights without identification

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a google docs spreadsheet. I want to share it with people that dont necessarily have a google account by just sending a URL.

It's ok if everyone has the same rights but what if I want some people with read only and others with read and write rights ?

Is it possible for instance to have two URLs :  one for read only and another for read and write ?

Comment: this question probably belongs on https://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks gman, I reposted on the stackexchange you suggested, do i have to close it here ?

Comment: can you delete it here? If not don't worry about it. Others will close it eventually